# Confusion about data flow on HTTP requests - what part is HTTP and what is JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, express, http

I'm going to use the following code as an example to frame my question. It's basically just the code required to pull a list of to dos from an SQLite3 database:

So, there's an axios request in the front end:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/todo', {})
    .then(res => {
        setTodoList(res.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
}, [])
```

...which links to the following function in the back end:

```
server.get('/todo', (req,res) => {
    // res.json(testData)
    const todos = db('todos') //this is shorthand for 'return everything from the table 'todos''
    .then(todos => {
        return res.json(todos)
    })
})
```

..the data from this GET request is then rendered within a react component, as a list of text.

I'm just confused about the flow of data - when is it HTTP, when is it JSON, what form does the data come out of the database as, and how is it that these different protocol/languages can talk to each other?

I get the overall principle of a GET request and async functions, I just don't get what's going on under the hood. Thanks!

Comment: http is a protocol. json is a data format. you seem to confuse them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of questions about basic issues. But here are some answers. Firstly, you can simplify the server function as:

```
server.get('/todo', (req, res) => {
  db('todos').then(todos => res.json(todos));
});
```

The data from the db is a Javascript array by the time you are dealing with it in Express. `res.json` converts it into JSON, which is of course, just a string.

Express creates an HTTP response, which consists of some headers (key value pairs such as Content-Length:  and so on) followed by a body, which in your case is just a JSON blob, a string. That response object is sent over the network via HTTP.

The browser receives the response and axios is kind enough to handle the grunt work of reading the headers and turning your JSON back into a Javascript array/object which can then be handled inside React.

The part I can't answer is "how is it that these different protocol/languages can talk to each other", because that is very complex and the question is not well defined. There are many network layers involved.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation - it all makes more sense now.

Comment: You’re welcome. Upvote and/or mark as answer always appreciated ;)